# How to select ALL children (in any level) from a parent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have to `.unbind()` all elements from a parent node.

How can I select all children (at any level) from a parent?

Tried :

```
$('#google_translate_element *').unbind('click');
```

but it works only for the first children's level...

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YPBxn/) there is a test case

Comment: Have you got a test case demonstrating this?

Comment: Can't you just do $('#google_translate_element').find('*').unbind('click');

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use [jQuery.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find children **more than one level** deep.

> The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

```
$('#google_translate_element').find('*').unbind('click');
```

You need the `'*'` in `find()`:

> Unlike in the rest of the tree traversal methods, the selector
>   expression is required in a call to .find(). If we need to retrieve
>   all of the descendant elements, we can pass in the universal selector
>   '*' to accomplish this.

Comment: i'm using this right now but do i have to worry about performance?

Comment: Yes, offcourse. You should always worry about performance. Modern browsers will be fairly quick in executing, but if you run into problems for this specific snippet, try keeping the parent element small (not too many children) or group the children in smaller sets.

Answer (score 22):

I think you could do:

```
$('#google_translate_element').find('*').each(function(){
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

but it would cause a lot of overhead

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the original test case is wrong.

I can confirm that the selector `#my_parent_element *` works with `unbind()`.

Let's take the following html as an example:

```
<div id="#my_parent_element">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">hello</div>
    <div class="div3">my</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div4">name</div>
  <div class="div5">
    <div class="div6">is</div>
    <div class="div7">
      <div class="div8">marco</div>
      <div class="div9">(try and click on any word)!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="unbind">Now, click me and try again</button>
```

And the jquery bit:

```
$('.div1,.div2,.div3,.div4,.div5,.div6,.div7,.div8,.div9').click(function() {
  alert('hi!');
})
$('button.unbind').click(function() {
  $('#my_parent_element *').unbind('click');
})
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fLvwbazk/7/