# Protractor click through elements and count children

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am experiencing problem with counting child elements while looping through collection of elements and clicking on every element using protractor. I am pretty new to that, and spent much time trying to figure out solution.

My current code looks like this:

```
function clickThroughElements(elements) {
        var amountOfChildElements = 0;
        for(var i in elements) {
          var element = elements[i];
          element.click();
          element.all(by.css('div')).then(function(elements) {
            amountOfChildElements += elements.length;
          });
        }
        return amountOfChildElements;
      }
```

Obviously I am getting 0 on return, because increment of amountOfChildElements is happening asynchronously. Can anybody recommend, how to properly return amountOfChildElements?

Comment: Hey not sure I understand the question is it just counting child elements contained within an element? This will do something basic http://jsbin.com/taxonejiri/edit?html,js,console,output also have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648761/how-to-select-all-children-in-any-level-from-a-parent-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid loops when promises are involved.

One way to get the count would be to first get all the counts as an array of promise with `map`. Then resolve them with `promise.all` and aggregate the values with `reduce`:

```
function clickThroughElements(elements) {
  var counts = elements.map(e => {
    e.click();
    return e.all(by.css('div')).count();
  });

  return protractor.promise.all(counts).then(values => {
    return values.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  });
}
```

Usage :

```
clickThroughElements(elements).then(count => {
    console.log(count);
});
```

Comment: Works as charm! Thank You very much for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can probably solve this using Protractor's `.each()`, and `.count()`.  This will keep everything asynchronous.

Something along the lines of this:

```
var totalChildren = 0;
var parents = element.all(by.css('div.class'));
// iterate through parent, equivalent of a for loop
parents.each(function (parent) {
    // parent is the element with the current index of your loop
    parent.click();
    // chain locator calls to parent, ensuring you are finding the correct child 
    // associated with the correct parent element
    parent.all(by.css('div')).count().then(function (count) {
        // count children of the current parent element
        totalChildren += count;
    });
});
```

Reference: [Protractor's element.all() functions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)