# How to access the css * selecter in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

what is the JavaScript / jquery equivalent of the following css operation.

```
.outer-content-warrap > * {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I tried using this, but it only works for the first child div, and not on other child div's

```js
$(".outer-content-warrap").children().css('background-color','yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer-content-warrap">
  <div>div1</div>
  <div>div2</div>
  <div>
    div3
    <div>div3.1</div>
    <div>
      div3.2
      <div>div3.2.1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[result of css:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKXtL.png)

[result of jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ME7P.png)

Comment: `$('.outer-content-warrap > *')` try that

Comment: @Dale - That's the same as what the OP is doing. (That is, the *result* is the same.)

Comment: Your code should work fine. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select ALL children (in any level) from a parent in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648761/how-to-select-all-children-in-any-level-from-a-parent-in-jquery)

Comment: Your code should be working. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: It's not quite the same but since jquery can make use of css selector just use the one that works :)

Comment: @tomerpacific No, this is not about _all_ levels of children.

Comment: @Dale i tried your solution it still doesn't give the result like the css one.

Comment: why the negative vote?

Comment: You need to put a code example in the question, as suggested above by 2 other people.  Adding links to images is no help whatsoever.  Edit the question and click the snippet button (looks like a document icon with `<>` in it).  You can there add HTML, CSS and Javascript to show what you've done and the outcomes, and they'll be within the question itself.

Comment: @IbrahimAliAsghar I didn't downvote but I guess because it's a duplicate and you don't gave us a reproducible example.

Comment: Here is an example showing that the selector works in the exact same way in both CSS and jQuery... http://jsfiddle.net/a0L21s6c/  Unless you can post code that demonstrates your problem I suggest that your issue lies elsewhere.  You've probably got some more CSS affecting the page elsewhere.

Comment: yes,  the code should and is working the same now, the real problem was with positioning of the jquery code, it is running as intended now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log('I have', $('.outer-content-warrap').length, '.outer-content-warrap');
console.log('I have', $('.outer-content-warrap').children().length, '.outer-content-warrap children');
console.log('I have', $('.outer-content-warrap > *').length, '.outer-content-warrap > *');

$('.outer-content-warrap').children().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');

setTimeout(() => { $('.outer-content-warrap > *').css('backgroundColor', 'orange'); }, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-content-warrap">
  <div>Yellow</div>
  <p>Yellow</p>
</div>

<div class="outer-content-warrap">
  <div>Yellow</div>
  <p>Yellow</p>
</div>
```

Both work as it's supposed to. Both grab the exact same number of children objects and applies successfully the background color. Probably there is another problem with your code. Please, post full code.