# Iterate through mutiple div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a model something

```
<div id="item">
  <div id ="subitem">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I access all the div inside the subitem and  every div  has different set of operations. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: please, try to take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648761/how-to-select-all-children-in-any-level-from-a-parent-in-jquery, and if you still have questions, please let me know what else is unclear for you. you receive all the items with `children` for single level, and `find` traverse more than 1 level. after you receive it, use a loop to iterate it. loop over each item like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735342/jquery-to-loop-through-elements-with-the-same-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method to get the children of element filtered by optional selector `"div"` and iterate over the matched DOM elements using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```js
$("#subitem").children("div").each(function () {
    console.log(this.id, this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="item">
  <div id ="subitem">
    <div id="first">abc data</div>
    <div id="two">xyz data</div>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please consider leaving a comment about why your code solves the OP's problem. The OP is new so I believe an explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.each()` and depending on what operations you want to run you can for example use `if` and `if else` statements.

```
$("#subitem > div").each(function() {
  if (this.id == "first") {
    console.log("found div with id " + this.id)
  } else if (this.id == "two") {
    console.log("found div with id " + this.id + ", and it's the second div")
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#subitem > div").each(function() {
  if (this.id == "first") {
    console.log("found div with id " + this.id)
  } else if (this.id == "two") {
    console.log("found div with id " + this.id + ", and it's the second div")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <div id="subitem">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.each()` method with help of `>` Child Selector and `*` Asterisk operator.

*Like:*
**element > ***  = Selects all `div` elements where the parent is a `#subitem` element.

**Useful Links:**
Combinators: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Each Method: https://api.jquery.com/each/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#subitem > *').each(function(i,v) {
        console.log($(this).text())
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item">
    <div id="subitem">
        <div id="first">First</div>
        <div id="two">Second</div>
        <div id="three">Third : <span>Sub-child</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `element > * = Selects all div elements where the parent is a #subitem element`. Wrong... It does select all div children but also every other element that is a direct child of subitem. If it should only select direct div children then it should be `$('#subitem > div')`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No, Not direct child of `#subitem` element because of I used `>` Child Selector then all child not sub-child affect.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam My comment is not that `>` is wrong but you say `element > * = Selects all div` and that is wrong. `element > div = Selects all div` would be correct

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added one `<span>` element inside `#three` div so you can click on `Run code snippet` for sub-child element check.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you for this information.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam `*` is a wildcard selector, meaning it will select anything. So if your 3 divs had a span sibling then that span would also be selected and not only the divs